# Pandas remove rows which any string

Tags: python, string, pandas, indexing, numeric

A very basic qs guys - thans vm for taking a look. I want to remove rows in `Col1` which contain any string - care about only numeric values in `Col1`.

Input:

```
      Col1  Col2 Col3
0      123  48.0  ABC
1       45  85.0  DEF
2    A.789  66.0  PQR
3    RN.35   9.0  PQR
4      LMO  12.0  ABC
```

Output:

```
      Col1  Col2 Col3
0    123.0  48.0  ABC
1     45.0  85.0  DEF
```

I tried

```
test = input_[input_['Col1'].str.contains(r'ABCDEGGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.')]
```

But see this error

> ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Could you:

- Give a short explanation as to why that's not working?
- What would be the alternate solution pls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do like this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("[a-zA-Z]+")
df.ix[df.col1.map(lambda x: regex.search(x) is None)]
```

Comment: so I did this:
'input_.ix[input_.Col1.map(lambda x: regex.search(x) is None)]'

and get the error:
'TypeError: expected string or buffer'

Comment: since I don't know type of col1, so I suppose it as string and do the process. if it's not , it will raise such exception. you can do this:
df.ix[df.col1.map(lambda x: regex.search(str(x)) is None)]
convert the col1 to string type and run it again.

Comment: boom! that did it - thanks vm.. Could I ask you as to why my way doesn't work pls?

Comment: My reconmendation is the book of <pandas for data analysis>. We don't need to dig to much of why it's wrong, we just need to know how to do in right way.

Answer (score 2):

Another faster solution with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and condition with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) where parameter `errors='coerce'` means if data are not numeric are converted to `NaN` - so you need find all not `NaN` data by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df.Col1, errors='coerce'))
0    123.0
1     45.0
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
Name: Col1, dtype: float64

print (pd.to_numeric(df.Col1, errors='coerce').notnull())
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: Col1, dtype: bool

df = df[pd.to_numeric(df.Col1, errors='coerce').notnull()]
print (df)
  Col1  Col2 Col3
0  123  48.0  ABC
1   45  85.0  DEF
```

**Timings**:

```
#[100000 rows x 3 columns]    
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [16]: %timeit (df.ix[df.Col1.map(lambda x: re.compile("[a-zA-Z]+").search(x) is None)])
10 loops, best of 3: 57.7 ms per loop

In [17]: %timeit (df[pd.to_numeric(df.Col1, errors='coerce').notnull()])
10 loops, best of 3: 22 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit (df[~df['Col1'].astype(str).str.contains(r'[ABCDEGGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.]', na=False)])
10 loops, best of 3: 38.8 ms per loop
```

---

Your solution:

I think you need cast to `str` by `astype` and then add `[]` [used to indicate a set of characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and last add parameter `na=False` because it seems some `NaN` value are in `col1` and then are converted to `False`:

```
print (df['Col1'].astype(str).str.contains(r'[ABCDEGGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.]', na=False))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: Col1, dtype: bool
```

Then need invert boolean mask by `~` and use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[~df['Col1'].astype(str).str.contains(r'[ABCDEGGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.]', na=False)])
  Col1  Col2 Col3
0  123  48.0  ABC
1   45  85.0  DEF
```

Comment: I add also timings of your solution, what is faster as accepted solution ;)